# Using client certificates with HttpListener

Tags: .net, ssl, httplistener

I'm using `HttpListener` to implement a simple web server. I'm binding to port 44430 -- I'm not port sharing with IIS. I've configured the server certificate by using `netsh`:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:44430 ^
    certhash=a614ebdfd07968dedd3afdb1cb8c696988dd7734 ^
    appid="{00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}"
```

Now, I'd like to require client certificates. I add `clientcertnegotiation=enable` to the above command, then it shows as enabled in `netsh http show sslcert`.

I use the following code in my server:

```
var context = listener.GetContext();
var clientCertificate = context.Request.GetClientCertificate();
```

...but when I browse to the site using Internet Explorer, then `clientCertificate` is `null`.

What am I missing?

Comment: IIRC, `clientcertnegotiation=enable` enables the client-certificate negotiation during the initial handshake. You should see a `Certificate Request` message if you look at the traffic with Wireshark (look at the packets on that port with "*Decode As... -> SSL*").

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a client certificate in your Windows Certificates store.

The certificate needs to be signed by a CA (Certificate Authority) that
is trusted on the server host.

Then IE should be able to find the client certificate and pass it to
the server.

Comment: It works fine with IIS on port 443. Question is: why isn't HttpListener negotiating for the client certificate? How do I configure that?